# How to declare a custom alertDialog static class?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have this layout.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQkWM.jpg

I'd like to create a class that displays this layout and a close button. I tried like this.

```
   public static class CounterDialog extends AlertDialog.Builder{

    public CounterDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }
}
```

But i dont know where should i declare the buttons and the onClickListener, so where do they go? In the constructor? and where do i set the setTitle,setCancelable,setButton properties too? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare the buttons and the onclickListener method in the constructor.Here is my code:

```
public static class CounterDialog extends AlertDialog.Builder{
    private TextView textView;

    public CounterDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);

        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null);
        setView(view);

        setTitle("mytitile!");

        textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        Button button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                textView.setText("click me!!!");


            }
        });
    }     

}
```

Here is my xml(the custom dialog xml):

```
R.layout.dialog:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:gravity="center" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="hahahaahahaha"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="click me!"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    />
 </LinearLayout>
```

You can create the custom dialog by using this:

```
CounterDialog counterDialog = new CounterDialog(this);
counterDialog.show();
```

"this" is the instance of your activity. And the setTitle, setCancelable can be invoked in  the constructor directly.

Comment: Thanks for the help!